# Contar linhas com PHP e JS

Tags: javascript, php

Eu estou precisando de uma função que me ajude a registrar em uma variável a quebra de linha e, posteriormente usando *java script*, exibisse na tela em tempo real o numero da linha.

Seria basicamente numerar a linha sendo que eu tenho que usar *PHP* para receber e *java script* apenas para exibir em tempo real.

Comment: Não entendi bem sua pergunta, mas você quer criar um contador de quebra de linhas? mas contar linhas do que? pode dar um exemplo?
obs:não posso comentar a sua pergunta pois não tenho reputação suficiente para tal.

Comment: @JahnKrauss      eu preciso criar um texte area e enquando eu digito eu preciso de uma funçao que registre a quantidade de linhas(cada linha que eu digitar) e que grave esse valor em uma variavel para que eu possa ir printando ela automaticamente com o Javascript, como se fosse um contador de linhas

Comment: @user7162 Seria algo desse tipo?
`function countLines(area)
{
var text = area.value.replace(/\s+$/g,"")
var split = text.split("\n")
return split.length
}`
Desculpe a formatação mas não sei porque não estou conseguindo formatar o texto depois basta enviar o resultado para uma variável php.

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta, mas não tenho certeza do que você quer. Se for pra exibir numeração linha a linha, especifique melhor na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript:

```
//Simplifiquei o JS, baseado na versão do @vmartins, muito mais enxuta
document.getElementById('texto').onkeyup = function() {
   count = this.value.split("\n").length;
   document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = count;
   document.getElementById('linhas').value = count;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <textarea id="texto" name="texto" onKeyup="updateLineCount()" rows="10"></textarea><br>
   <input type="hidden" id="linhas" name="linhas" value="0">
   Linhas: <span id="contador"></span>
</form>
```

Veja demonstração no [SQL Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6Z5s/)

> Nota: a contagem de linhas vai ser enviada num *field* oculto, para atender à pergunta, no entanto o ideal é recontar via PHP, e não enviar o valor, pois este pode ser modificado manualmente e/ou simulado.

### PHP:

(não estamos usando o campo oculto do HTML, mas sim "recontando" via PHP)

```
<?php
   $texto = $_POST('texto');
   $linhas = explode("\n", $texto);
   $conta = count($linhas);
   //... se for mostrar as linhas individualmente,
   //    pode iterar a array $linhas aqui ...
   echo $conta;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obter em javascript o total de linhas de um textarea, você pode fazer algo como:

```
seu_textarea.value.split('\n').length
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/yTRwD/

Já no PHP, você pode utilizar a função [substr_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-count.php) para contar o total de quebra de linhas em uma string.

```
substr_count($_POST['seu_textarea'], "\n");
```